# dismissModalViewController not working when enqueued on main queue

Tags: iphone, modalviewcontroller, grand-central-dispatch

I've problems dismissing a modalviewcontroller inside a background queue. Here is the code

```
- (void)cleanUpPictures
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("ch.thurboapp.cleanup", NULL);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self.managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator]];
        //register for core data save notification
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                                                     name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                   object:context];
        [self deleteAllObjects:@"Thumbnail" inContext:context];
        [self deleteAllObjects:@"MenuThumbnail" inContext:context];
        [self deleteAllObjects:@"PictureData" inContext:context];
        [context release];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:LastCleaned];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        });
    });
    dispatch_release(queue);
}
```

the

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

gets called inside the main thread, but with no effect. Someone knows a solution for this problem?

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with how UI code interacts within blocks, but have you tried the simpler performSelectorOnMainThread?

Comment: Make sure parentViewController isn't nil.  Also, make sure it's the correct view controller that is presently being displayed modally.

Comment: the parentViewController and the parent's childModalViewController are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dispatch group to notify you when the first block of work has completed:

```
- (void)cleanUpPictures
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("ch.thurboapp.cleanup", NULL);
    // To know when we're done, we need to associate work in this queue
    // with a group
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[self.managedObjectContext persistentStoreCoordinator]];
    //register for core data save notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(mergeChanges:)
                                                 name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                               object:context];
    [self deleteAllObjects:@"Thumbnail" inContext:context];
    [self deleteAllObjects:@"MenuThumbnail" inContext:context];
    [self deleteAllObjects:@"PictureData" inContext:context];
    [context release];
});

// When the last block of work in this group finishes
// dispatch_group_notify fires
dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:LastCleaned];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    });

dispatch_release(queue);
dispatch_release(group);
}
```